# What is the name for a portion of a spherical segment?

Tags: geometry, definition, spheres, spherical-geometry

See the definition of a spherical segment [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment).

If I split the spherical segment into three, for example, such that the top and bottom edges of each piece were arcs of a circle corresponding to a third of a circle, what would each piece be called?

Is there a name for it or are they simply portions of a spherical segment?

Comment: Try spherical lune.

Comment: That wouldn't cover it I think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_lune